# Coding challenge on career cup, finding the smallest sum partition

Tags: c++, arrays

**Question:**

> Given an integer array. Find out the equal sum partition with the smallest sum.
>   For example: a = [1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3]. There are three equal sum partitions: [(1, 3), (2, 2), (1, 3)], [(1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3)] and [(1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3)]. First one has the smallest equal sum, so return 4
>   Notice you cannot reorder the input array.

**Thoughts:**

Initially I want to keep summing every two pair, every three pair,...,etc until the only subarray left would be the array itself. Then I would be able to isolate the minimum with that approach. Although, I feel like this is a decent strategy I am lost on how to achieve implementing this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking how to count pairs of elements in an array? i.e. given an array of 6 elements, you're not sure how to break it down into 3 lots of 2 (then subsequently two lots of 3).

Comment: @Tas I guess so, I mean I am now thinking of using a mod operator to break it up, is that a correct approach?

Comment: One way of thinking about it is for an array of 6 elements, you need to break it down into 3x2, 2x3 and 1x6. Notice these are all factors of 6. So you probably want to get the factors of a number, then break the array down into those numbers.

Comment: you may divide the full array to two. so if 6 elements do the sum, then divide into two , left and right. . do the left rray with sum of 1,2nd index and do the sum on 2nd and 3rd index. you then do the same for the right side. kind of like merge sort algo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v) 
{
    for (auto& val : v) {
        os << val << " ";
    }
    os << std::endl;
    return os;
}

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v) 
{
    for (auto& v2 : v) {
        os << "| ";
        for (auto& v3 : v2) {
            os << v3 << " ";
        }
    }
    os << "|" << std::endl;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3};
    //std::cout << v;

    std::vector<int> partitionsums;
    partitionsums.push_back(std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0));

    // for each number we can get that divides the v.size()
    for (size_t i = 2; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if (v.size() % i == 0) {

            const size_t cnt = i;
            const size_t len = v.size() / i;
            //std::cout << len << " " << i << "\n";

            // we create `cnt` number of vectors each of `len` size
            std::vector<std::vector<int>> vs;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < cnt; ++j) {
                std::vector<int> tmp;
                for (size_t k = 0; k < len; ++k) {
                    const size_t idx = j * len + k;
                    tmp.push_back(v[idx]);
                }
                vs.push_back(tmp);
            }

            //std::cout << vs;

            // for each vector we need to calculate the sum
            std::vector<int> sums;
            for (auto& v2 : vs) {
                sums.push_back(std::accumulate(v2.begin(), v2.end(), 0));
            }

            // if all sums are the same, add the sum value to the set
            if (std::unique(sums.begin(), sums.end()) == sums.begin() + 1) {
                partitionsums.push_back(sums.front());
            }
        }
    }

    // get the smallest sum of the partitions
    std::sort(partitionsums.begin(), partitionsums.end());
    const int smallest_sum = partitionsums.front();

    std::cout << "The smallest sum of partitions of vector: " << v << "\tis: " << smallest_sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Live version available at [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/rkZ6JBx9m).

Use dynamic programming and split the problem into sub-problems:

1. Create a "partition" of the input array of defined size
2. Calculate the sum of all partitioned arrays
3. Check if the sum is unique
4. Find the smallest of unique sums.